# How to consume a storage queue from data factory pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I am working on a project where I need to consume the entries of the storage queue from a data factory pipeline.

Files will be uploaded to a blob storage which triggers a azure function. This azure function writes into a storage queue. Now I want to consume the entries of this storage queue. Due to the fact that the storage queue provide a rest api to consume data, I can use a web client in the azure data factory which can be scheduled every few minutes. But I would prefere a more direct way, so that when the storage queue has been filled, my pipeline should be starting.

I am quite new to the azure world, so now I am searching for solution. Is there a way to subscribe to the storage queue? I can see that there is the possibilty to create custom triggers in the data factory how can I connect to a storage queue there? Or is there another way?

Comment: what are you doing with the messages on the storage queue and why do you need to do it with data factory?

Comment: The idea behind this is to decouple it and to have the control if something goes wrong during the pipeline process. I know that I could directly call the pipeline by using the storage event oncreate but this will be called once.

Comment: you could have a logic app (or function) handle the queue events and call the Data Factory pipeline.  It seems that might be better than have the data factory pipeline running every few minutes to look for events.  The Logic App or Function can be triggered by the queue directly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Scott Mildenberger for pointing out in the right direction. After taking the inputs and reproducing from my end, this was working when I used Queue Trigger called `When a specified number of messages are in a given queue (V2)` where we can specify the Threshold of the Queue to get the flow triggered. Below is the flow of my Logic App.

[image]

***RESULTS:***

*In Logic App*

[image]

*In ADF*

[image]